# how to install extension without composer

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I want to install this extension in my project where i have integrated a new template :evincemage/module-trackorder . I tried  with empty project(without template ) it works but with template it does 'nt appear please help

Comment: Hi..how can we help you?

Comment: Can you specify, when you try to install, which error occures?

Comment: when t acces the /track order/index/index i got 404 error

Comment: i have the menu of name extension uderstore config and the module is enabled but i don't have the link tarck order in the top menu and when i tried to acces /id route/namecontroller/nameaction i got 404 error

Comment: you can contact us

Comment: how to contact them exactly please

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your module is installed successfully, please modify/check these things:

1. Open `app/etc/config.php` and find your module registered name here. The value should be 1.
2. Access table `setup_module` in your database, find your module registered name here. It must be listed here with valid values of `schema_version` and `data_version`.
3. If 1 & 2 are ok, you don't need to run `setup:upgrade` command again. Just clear the cache by using these commands below (I don't use Magento commands because sometimes they do not work as expected):

   ```
   rm -rf pub/static/frontend
   rm -rf var/cache
   rm -rf var/page_cache
   rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
   ```
4. Reload your Frontend to get result.

**Notice**: Do not remove `.htaccess` file in `pub/static` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can install extension using Web Wizard tool instead composer. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

Comment: This is to install magento not extension

Answer (score 0):

To install without composer:

Copy the module folder in var/code folder then run:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento static:content:depoly
```

the last command will handle the the template problems.

Comment: app/code folder

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all folder from evincemage/module-trackorder
and Paste that folder to app/Code/Evincemage/Trackorder 
and finallu run upgrade and deploy command and check.

I hope this will help you
Happy Coding !!!